# Sonata No site available for the current request

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin, sonata

I setup Sonata-Page ,  Admin ... on Symfony 4

[image]

ip http://10.2.0.6 is docker server ip

Run

```
 bin/console sonata:page:create-snapshots --site=all
 bin/console sonata:page:update-core-routes --site=all
```

enable Page

[image]

But always have

[image]

In

In Sonata\PageBundle\Site public function retrieve() i get

```
arrayPrint.php on line 64:
HostSiteSelector {#211 ▼
  #siteManager: SiteManager {#220 ▶}
  #decoratorStrategy: DecoratorStrategy {#213 ▶}
  #seoPage: SeoPage {#214 ▶}
  #site: null
```

Who fill this var , why is empty ?

i see listener (Sonata\PageBundle\Listener\RequestListener onCoreReques ) is fired and try get from this method site object.

in same class i see

```
protected function getSites(Request $request)
```

when i dump this i get

```
arrayPrint.php on line 64:
array:1 [▼
  0 => SonataPageSite {#460 ▼
    #id: 1
    #enabled: true
    #createdAt: DateTime @1533546625 {#483 ▶}
    #updatedAt: DateTime @1533541412 {#505 ▶}
    #name: "localhost"
    #host: "10.2.0.6"
    #relativePath: null
    #enabledFrom: DateTime @1533546622 {#484 ▶}
    #enabledTo: DateTime @1849165822 {#464 ▶}
    #isDefault: true
    #formats: []
    #locale: "en_GB"
    #title: null
    #metaKeywords: null
    #metaDescription: null
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok i Found reason - i create page like manual say

```
php app/console  sonata:page:create-site --enabled=true --name=localhost --locale=- --host=localhost --relativePath=/ --enabledFrom=now --enabledTo="+10 years" --default=true
```

enabledFrom=now , i dont know why but give my time in GMT not my timezone, so site is not visible in current time, if i wait hour site start by visible. I think this is not good. In default page should by visible without limits not in range.